# the release .aab version of the application crashes

Tags: android, crash, google-play-console, google-developers-console

The release .aab version of the application immediately crashes when its downloaded from the play store, but when its installed with Android Studio or apk everything is fine

I tried to find solutions but there are no right solutions anywhere

Сan you tell me how to fix it, please

there is Stack trace from google play console

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3334)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3473)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)        
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2067)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7519)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

I have only one activity:

```
class ValidationActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

private lateinit var navController: NavController
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
lateinit var pref: CookiePreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_validation)

    pref = CookiePreferences.getInstance(this)!!

    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf( 
            R.id.loginFragment,
            R.id.eventsFragment
        )
    )

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        if(destination.id == R.id.loginFragment) {    
            toolbar.visible(false) 
        } else {
            toolbar.visible(true)
        }

    }

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.valid_app_bar_menu, menu)
    val item: MenuItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.app_bar_logout)!!
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
        if(destination.id == R.id.eventsFragment) {   
            item.isVisible = true
        } else {
            item.isVisible = true
        }
    }

    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return if (item.itemId == R.id.app_bar_logout) {
        pref.deleteCookiesPrefs()
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_loginFragment)
        true
    } else {
        item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

}

full stack from adb logcat:

```
259 17259 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanners, PID: 17259
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanners/com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanner.ui.validations.ValidationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanners:layout/activity_validation: Binary XML file line #30 in com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanners:layout/activity_validation: Error inflating class fragment
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3700)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3879)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2315)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:260)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8265)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanners:layout/activity_validation: Binary XML file line #30 in com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanners:layout/activity_validation: Error inflating class fragment
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanners:layout/activity_validation: Error inflating class fragment
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanners:navigation/valid_nav line 33
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.navigation.p.c(Unknown Source:119)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.navigation.NavController.j(:2)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.I(:26)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.h0.e(:1)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.h0.k(:8)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.z.onCreateView(:10)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.fragment.app.q.onCreateView(:4)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at e.l.v(Unknown Source:23)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at e.i.setContentView(Unknown Source:7)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanner.ui.validations.ValidationActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:16)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8146)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8130)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3669)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3879)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2315)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:260)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8265)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanner.data.models.Events
05-30 17:44:38.394 17259 17259 E A
```

navigation/valid_nav, live 39 is on app:argType="com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanner.data.models.Show"

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/validationContainerFragment"
    android:name="com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanner.ui.validations.validation.ValidationContainerFragment"
    android:label="@string/validation"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_validation_container" >
    <argument
        android:name="show"
        app:argType="com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanner.data.models.Show" />
</fragment>
```

Show class:

```
import java.io.Serializable

data class Show(
   val name: String,
   val ts: String,
   val uid: String
) : Serializable
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace from `adb logcat` when you install it on your phone from Play?

Comment: @Pierre I added everything and thanks for tip about adb logcat its usefull, but issue is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the cause of the stacktrace, it says:

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.ticketonpartners.ticketonscanner.data.models.Events
```

I suspect you use this class in your definition of your view `navigation/valid_nav` but this class is obfuscated by your proguard configuration.

You may need to tweak your proguard keep rules to not remove or rename this class.